# Merge dots into line (with css filter?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you merge dots (`<div>`s) into a line in css?

I have the following grid made up of `<divs>`:

```
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:-5;    top:-5;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:15;    top:-5;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:35;    top:-5;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:55;    top:-5;"></div>

    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:-5;    top:15;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:15;    top:15;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:35;    top:15;    width:30px;    height:30px;    background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="gridBlock" style="left:55;    top:15;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#outer-container {
    padding: 48px;
    filter: brightness(1.4) contrast(40); /* ? */
}
#container {
    position: absolute;
    filter: blur(10px) brightness(1.4) contrast(100); /* ? */
}

.gridBlock {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: .5px solid black;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-grid;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This would look like (no css filter):
[image]

How would I make this into a line?

I have tried using css `filter`, but it doesn't really work, see screenshot below: 
[image]

What I want:

[image]

#### a more complex example

No css `filter`:

[image]

With css `filter`

[image]

This is not quite what I want, as it interferes with the colors and is blurry around the edges.

I have seen [this](http://css-tricks.com/shape-blobbing-css/), but it wasn't very helpful for this situation.

A JavaScript solution would be okay as well.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe you can use SVG gooey effect described here https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this